# JavaScript for Project Euler problems

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve [Q10](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=10) from Project Euler. I am using JavaScript and [Sieve of Atkins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) algorithm to solve the problem. When I run the code on browsers(Safari and FF) the browsers prompts that the script is unresponsive. Even if I let the script to continue I never got the answer. I know there are threads for the same Project Euler problem.

My questions would be:-

1.How far JavaScript is capable to solve such complex mathematical problems for browsers?

2.Is there any other environment where I can I test my JavaScript programs?

Thank you All.

Comment: You might want to use web workers (HTML5); they run in a separate thread so as not to let your browser freeze. Concerning JavaScript speed, this changes everyday with the browser updates...

Comment: This sounds like a job for [node.js](http://nodejs.org).  Or you could write it in some other scripting language to see if it finishes, and then convert it to JavaScript.

Comment: It's definitely possible with the right algorithm. If it freezes (for longer than a few seconds), your algorithm is just not good enough yet.

Comment: Isn't Atkins a bit overkill? For the numbers smaller than two millions even a brute force approach in javascript (just looping over all odd numbers starting at 3 and check if they're prime) solves the question in about one second on chrome...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. I would have thought as capable as any other - JavaScript implementations have been optimised a lot in recent years thanks to increased used in the web.
2. You can use either [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) or [CScript](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490887.aspx) (a command line version of the Windows Script host - this is supplied as part of Windows).

If I remember my implementation of that question (in Python) was significantly slower than I thought it would be.  The chances are the slowness is due to your algorithm rather than the language.

Answer (score 6):

The goal of project Euler is to get you thinking, mathematically.
Think of brute forcing, and you will be stuck. 
Here is an implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes

---

```
function problem10() {

    var i, j, k, l = Math.floor((2000000-1)/2), a = [];
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        a[i] = true;
    } var m = Math.sqrt(2000000);
    for (i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
        if (a[i]) {
            j = 2 * i + 3;
            k = i + j;
            while (k < l) {
                a[k] = false;
                k += j;
            }
        }
    } var s = 2;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (a[i]) {
            s += 2 * i + 3;
        }
    }
    return s;

}

var d1 = new Date().getTime();
var answer = problem10();
var d2 = new Date().getTime();

console.log('Answer:' + answer + ' time:' + (d2 - d1));
```

---

You can run it on the chrome developer's console (Ctrl + Shift + J).
And guess what, it clocks 0.1 second.

Answer (score 3):

```
function problem10(){

    var a = 0;

    function isPrime(n){
        var i = 2;
        var b = true;
        while(i<=Math.sqrt(n) && b){
            b = n%i===0?false:true;
            i++;
        }
        return n<2?false:b;
    }

    for(i=0;i<2000000;i++){
        if(isPrime(i)){
            a+=i;
        }
    }
    return a;

}
```

Comment: Where did you test this did you test it in a browser? wich browser and so on.

Comment: @PabloKarlsson, I wrote it in chrome. are you having any problems running it?

Answer (score 2):

You could try testing your implementation on [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

However, I would bet that you have a problem with your code.  JavaScript in a modern browser is pretty quick (and generally you should get Project Euler answers very quickly; it's not designed to require high amounts of computing power).