# Output Javascript array into HTML with better readability

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to output the data in an array (produced by [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15471749/4676640)) to a div in a simple web page, using this jquery:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();    
        var num = $('#userInput').val();       
        var primes = sieve(num);          // sieve() produces array of prime numbers
        console.log(primes);          
        $('#answer').html(primes);
    });
```

The console is logging the array as I would like to see it, (i.e. 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, etc.) but the content in #answer is displaying without any formatting (23571113 etc.).

How can I get the data to display in a more readable format? I've tried using .split and .join to add commas or line breaks but no joy...

Comment: Have you tried `$('#answer').text(primes)`?

Comment: If `primes` is an array then `$('#answer').html(primes.join(','));` should work.

Answer (score 6):

Just join the array into a string using whatever separator you want to use. Also, when filling in text that isn't HTML, don't use [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html), use [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text):

```
$('#answer').text(primes.join(", "));
```

---

You (and lurkers) may be wondering why you didn't get the default `Array#toString` behavior, which is to do `.join()` (where `join` defaults to the separator `","`). The reason is that the `html` function is appending each element of the array to the target element individually, as a new text node, instead of calling `toString` on the array. (This doesn't appear to be [documented behavior](http://api.jquery.com/html/).) Surprising, but true:

```js
var answer = $("#answer");
answer.html([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
console.log(answer[0].childNodes.length); // 5
```

```html
<div id="answer"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`text` applies `toString`, but the default separator used (`","`, no space after `,`) probably isn't what you want:

```js
var answer = $("#answer");
answer.text([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
console.log(answer[0].childNodes.length); // 5
```

```html
<div id="answer"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to use `.text()` instead of `.html()` to set the contents of the #answer element.  You must also join the values of the array using the `.join()` method.

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();    
        var num = $('#userInput').val();       
        var primes = sieve(num);          // sieve() produces array of prime numbers
        console.log(primes);          
        $('#answer').text(primes.join(", "));
    });
```

Or, if you really want to add it as HTML, wrap it in a `pre` element, which preserves whitespace:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();    
        var num = $('#userInput').val();       
        var primes = sieve(num);          // sieve() produces array of prime numbers
        console.log(primes);          
        $('#answer').html('<pre>' + primes.join(", ") + '</pre>');
    });
```

Comment: @T.J Crowder, true, not since he just needed a single space between each number. Answer updated.