# Why is this implementation of Sieve of Eratosthenes incorrect?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sieve-of-eratosthenes

The goal is to find the sum of all primes up till num. I've seen the same implementation on another post, but it also doesn't work: [Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm in JavaScript running endless for large number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471291/sieve-of-eratosthenes-algorithm-in-javascript-running-endless-for-large-number)

However, the solution there is also incorrect when I try it with 977, it returns 72179, but it should be 73156.

```
const sumPrimes = num => {
    var numList = [];
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        numList.push(true);
    }

    for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
        if (numList[i]) {
            for (var j = i * i; j < num; j += i) {
                numList[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    for (var k = 2; k < num; k++) {
        if (numList[k]) {
            output.push(k);
        }
    }
    var sum = output.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0);
    console.log(output);
    return sum;
};
```

Pseudocode obtained from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. It returns the sum of primes less than `num`, and the sum of primes less than 977 is 72179. Your expected answer of 73156 is the sum of primes less than *or equal to* 977. The difference is 977 because 977 is prime.